# kotlin priority Queue not working as expected

Tags: kotlin, priority-queue

So, I'm trying to make myself familiar with priorityQueue in kotlin/java,

```kotlin
val pq = PriorityQueue<Int>(){p0,p1->
    p0-p1
}

pq.add(6)
pq.add(1)
pq.add(2)
pq.add(11)
```

Output

```
pq = {PriorityQueue@1937}  size = 4
 0 = {Integer@1944} 1
 1 = {Integer@1945} 6
 2 = {Integer@1946} 2
 3 = {Integer@1947} 11
```

Shouldn't the output be sorted ascending?

The interesting thing descending is working fine.

```kotlin
val pq = PriorityQueue<Int>(){p0,p1->
    p1-p0
}

pq.add(6)
pq.add(1)
pq.add(2)
pq.add(11)
```

```
pq = {PriorityQueue@1944}  size = 4
 0 = {Integer@1950} 11
 1 = {Integer@1951} 6
 2 = {Integer@1952} 2
 3 = {Integer@1953} 1
```

Comment: You need to provide the code you're using to output.

Comment: How are you producing the output? Also have you read the documentation of `PriorityQueue`? For example, for the [Java `PriorityQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/PriorityQueue.html), only `poll`, `remove`, `peek`, and `element` are guaranteed to produce the right order. Any other means of inspection will return the elements in an undefined order. I guess you're looking at it with your debugger, and in that case, the order is basically undefined.

Comment: Completely precise observation by @MarkRotteveel. Using `repeat(4) { println(pq.poll()) }` outputs the expected order.

Comment: You are right, thank you